# What does "Moth" mean here in Agatha Christie's Peril at End House?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context, proper-nouns

> 'George hasn't turned up,' said Nick. 'A nuisance his having to go
>   back to Plymouth last night. He'll get over this evening sometime or
>   other, I expect. In time for the dance anyway. I've got a man for
>   Maggie. Presentable, if not passionately interesting.'
>
> A faint roaring sound drifted in through the window.
>
> 'Oh! curse that speedboat,' said Lazarus. 'I get so tired of it.'
>
> 'That's not the speedboat,' said Nick. 'That's a sea-plane.'
>
> 'I believe you're right.'
>
> 'Of course I'm right. The sound's quite different.'
>
> **'When are you going to get your Moth, Nick?'**
>
> 'When I can raise the money,' laughed Nick.
>
> 'And then, I suppose you'll be off to Australia like that girl-what's
>   her name?'
>
> 'I'd love to-'
>
> 'I admire her enormously,' said Mrs. Rice, in her tired voice. 'What
>   marvelous nerve! All by herself too.'
>
> 'I admire all these flying people,' said Lazarus. 'If Michael Seton
>   had succeeded in his flight round the world he'd have been the hero of
>   the day-and rightly so. A thousand pities he's come to grief. He's the
>   kind of man England can't afford to lose.' (*Peril at End House,* Agatha Christie)

I suppose Moth here refers to an expensive brand/thing but can't figure out exactly what. The phrase in question is bolded.

Comment: I'm really tempted to downvote, because the question shows no research effort at all. [Wikipedia's disambiguation page for "Moth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moth_(disambiguation)) includes both answers given as of now ("plane" and "boat").

Comment: I apologize for the seemingly lack of research effort. I had actually searched quite a lot online but it didn't occur to me at that time that it was actually a plane/boat. But if I had known this, I wouldn't have posted this question.

Answer (score 27):

The [de Havilland Moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Moth) was a line of airplanes manufactured in the 1920's and 1930's.

Since they are talking about airplanes, and the book was published in 1932, that may be the answer.

According to Wikipedia:

> Every light aircraft flying in the UK was commonly referred to as a 'Moth', regardless if it was de Havilland-built or not.

Comment: Just like today most people call any light airplane a Cessna, even if not manufactured by them.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative to the sailboat mentioned by Helmar, it could refer to the [De Havilland Tiger Moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Tiger_Moth), a popular biplane used as a trainer from 1931 into the '50s. Al Stewart's "Flying Sorcery" sings of

> You were taking off in Tiger Moths,
>
> Your wings against the brush strokes of the day.

In this case, "your Moth" would be a familiar contraction. Since "Peril at End House" was published in 1932, the timing fits (although just barely).

Answer (score 2):

It's a kind of sailboat. Wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moth_(dinghy)

As the other answer points out it could be a plane as well.

Both the boat and the plane stem from the 1930s.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Moth (plane)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Moth (boat)

I guess you have to decide based on the rest of the book if he's gonna buy a plane or a boat.

Comment: I reckon a plane: that dinghy looks much too small to get to Australia; it's after hearing a sea-plane; and afterwards they're still talking about "all these flying people".

Comment: "...off to Australia like that girl-what's her name?"  clearly refers to [Amy Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amy_Johnson), or certainly would to people at the time. A journey she undertook in a de Havilland Gypsy Moth.

Answer (score 2):

"off to Australia like that girl" refers to Amy Johnson, who made the first flight between Britain and Australia in a Gypsy Moth. At the time the book was written the planes were very well known. I've never heard of the boat.